# not able to autowire bean in prototype scope in a singleton bean using @Lookup annotation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have created below classes and interfaces but prototype bean constructor is not getting called. I am using @Lookup for creating prototype scoped bean.

```
public interface IProtoTypeBean {}

@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ProtoTypeBean implements IProtoTypeBean {

    public ProtoTypeBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("ProtoTypeBean");
    }
}

@Component
public class SingleTonBean {

    IProtoTypeBean protoTypeBean = getProtoTypeBean();

    @Lookup
    public ProtoTypeBean getProtoTypeBean(){
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SingleTonBean.class);
        SingleTonBean s1 = ctx.getBean(SingleTonBean.class);
        IProtoTypeBean p1 = s1.protoTypeBean;
        SingleTonBean s2 = ctx.getBean(SingleTonBean.class);
        IProtoTypeBean p2 = s2.protoTypeBean;
        System.out.println("singelton beans " + (s1 == s2));

        // if ProtoTypeBean constructor getting called 2 times means diff objects are getting created
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the below steps

```
 @Component("protoBean")
@Scope(value = "prototype") public class ProtoTypeBean implements IProtoTypeBean {
```

And

```
@Lookup(value="protoBean")
public abstract ProtoTypeBean getProtoTypeBean();
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, where should I define abstract getProtoTypeBean method.

Comment: Update the getProtoTypeBean()  and make it abstract

Comment: should I put inside another abstract class

Comment: I hope you are reading my comments properly, I have mentioned to make getProtoTypeBean()  abstract

Comment: thanks it worked, I was using  IProtoTypeBean p1 = s1.protoTypeBean; to get bean instead I should have used IProtoTypeBean p1 = s1.getProtoTypeBean();

Comment: Kindly mark the solution as accepted if it solved the problem or vote up if it contributed to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **prototype provider**.

Add maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then mention both classes to be managed by Spring

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SingleTonBean.class, ProtoTypeBean.class);
```

And here is the provider usage

```
    @Component
    public class SingleTonBean {

    @Autowired
    private Provider<IProtoTypeBean> protoTypeBeanProvider;

    public IProtoTypeBean getProtoTypeBean() {
        return protoTypeBeanProvider.get();
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SingleTonBean.class, ProtoTypeBean.class);
        SingleTonBean s1 = ctx.getBean(SingleTonBean.class);
        IProtoTypeBean p1 = s1.getProtoTypeBean();
        SingleTonBean s2 = ctx.getBean(SingleTonBean.class);
        IProtoTypeBean p2 = s2.getProtoTypeBean();
        System.out.println("singleton beans " + (s1 == s2));
        System.out.println("prototype beans " + (p1 == p2));
    }
}
```

Comment: please let me know if there is any advantage of using Provider instead of Lookup annotation

Comment: @VikrantChaudhary, IMHO provider is usage is more cleaner technique. There is a factory autowired by Spring and it has method get() creating new prototype bean. On the contrary, lookup method returns null although it will be overrided by Spring.